# Regex and replacement with numbers and texts

Tags: regex, replace, numbers, calibre

In a epub code, I have this text:

```
<span>Capitulo 1 - Apple is red</span>
<span>Capitulo 2 - Milk is white</span>
<span>Capitulo 3 - Weeds are green</span>
```

I need to replace "span" tags with "h1" tags, and all instances of "capitulo" with "chapter", mantaining the rest of the text. I tried this in calibre, with no fortune:

```
Find: <span>Capitulo (/d+) * </span>
Replace: <h1>Chapter /1 * </h1>
```

What can i do?

**2nd question:**
If i had this text:

```
<span>Capitulo 1 - apple is red, 5 chicas</span>
<span>Capitulo 2 - milk is white, 6 chicas</span>
<span>Capitulo 3 - weeds are green, 7 chicas</span>
```

and i want to obtain:

```
<h1>Chapter1 - apple is red, 5 girls</h1>
<h2>Chapter2 - milk is white, 6 boys</h2>
<h3>Chapter3 - weeds are green, 7 men</h3>
```

how should i proceed?

Comment: `<span>Capitulo ([^<]*)</span>` => `<h1>Chapter \1</h1>`

Comment: You can try this `<span>Capitulo(\s*\d+.*?)<\/span>`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZsQcgv/1/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Isn't it necessary to escape `<`, `>` and `/`?

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov None of these is a special char, so why escape?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, correct, although `/` is a special char in PCRE, it's probably not the case in Calibre.

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov `/` is [not special in PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/DggwZ8/1). `/` should only be escaped in regex literals, and text editors only use string patterns.

Comment: @CodeManiac It is not special in JS, it acts as a regex delimiter in regex literal notation and then it must be escaped. `new RegExp('/')` - no escaping necessary as `/` is  **not a special regex metacharacter**, period.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes in case of using regeExp with regex literal notation we need to escape it, yeah Metacharacter is more perfect name

Comment: @CodeManiac sure, but it does not make `/` "special" in the meaning of a "special regex metacharacter".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah you're right i meant that only but used wrong name, thanks for pointing out

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just out of curosity because your regex looks more cleaner that what i have wrtten, will your regex takes care of input like `<span>Capitulo 1 - Apple is <> red</span>`,

Comment: @CodeManiac I'd say that your string has an error. Judging by the sample input, there should be no child tags inside the `span`s OP is targeting. `.*?` or `[\s\S]*?` would solve the issue you mention. Unless there might be nested `span` tags, but that is already out of scope here. If there are tags inside these `spans` I would not use a text editor to handle them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew inside value is just text and having `<` or `>` is not error i guess ( what i mean is let's say i have some expression inside span  like x < y ), yeah thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

**Find**: `<span>Capitulo ([^<]*)</span>` 
**Replace**: `<h1>Chapter \1</h1>`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VC21q5/1) and the Regulex graph:

[image]

The `([^<]*)` part matches any 0 or more characters other than `<` as `[^<]` is a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and the `(...)` form a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) whose contents are accessible from the replacement pattern via [**backreferences**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) (see `\1` in the replacement).